# xsl nested loops failure

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file from calibre that I am using and have experienced a problem when nesting xsl:for-each.

XML file:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<calibredb>
  <record>
    <title sort="Demon Under the Microscope, The">The Demon Under the Microscope</title>
    <authors sort="Hager, Thomas">
      <author>Thomas Hager</author>
    </authors>
  </record>
  <record>
    <title sort="101 Things Everyone Should Know About Math">101 Things Everyone Should Know About Math</title>
    <authors sort="Zev, Marc &amp; Segal, Kevin B. &amp; Levy, Nathan">
      <author>Marc Zev</author>
      <author>Kevin B. Segal</author>
      <author>Nathan Levy</author>
    </authors>
  </record>
  <record>
    <title sort="Biohazard">Biohazard</title>
    <authors sort="Alibek, Ken">
      <author>Ken Alibek</author>
    </authors>
  </record>
  <record>
    <title sort="Infectious Madness">Infectious Madness</title>
    <authors sort="WASHINGTON, HARRIET">
      <author>Harriet A. Washington</author>
    </authors>
  </record>
  <record>
    <title sort="Poetry Will Save Your Life">Poetry Will Save Your Life</title>
    <authors sort="Bialosky, Jill">
      <author>Jill Bialosky</author>
    </authors>
  </record>
</calibredb>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My Calibre Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="calibredb/record">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
        <td><xsl:for-each select="authors"><xsl:value-of select="author" /></xsl:for-each></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It seems that if multiple authors are present, the loop fails to continue further.

Could anyone give me a suggestion on how to format the xsl correctly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1.0 `xsl:value-of` is only going to give you the value of the first `author`.

Instead of selecting `authors` in the inner for-each, try selecting `authors/author`...

```
<xsl:for-each select="authors/author">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

You’ll probably want to also output a comma or some other delimiter to separate the values...

```
<xsl:for-each select="authors/author">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

This failure has actually nothing to do with the nested loop.
Notice that each `record` element has **only one** `authors` element,
so the inner `xsl:for-each select="authors"` is not needed
(it will make only 1 turn).

The problem is in other place, namely in `value-of` instruction.
Your case is an example of a weird feature of **XSLT 1.0** concerning `value-of`,
that many XSLT users are not aware of.

Even if `select` phrase retrieved **multiple** nodes,
then `value-of` prints **only the first of them**, not the whole sequence,
and (IMHO) this is not what an average XSLT user expects.

Only as late as in version **2.0** this was made in a more intuitive way.

`value-of` instruction in **XSLT 2.0** will print in this case
**the whole sequence**, inserting between them a separator specified
with `separator` attribute.

So if you can move on to version **2.0**, just write:

```
<xsl:for-each select="calibredb/record">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="authors/author" separator=", "/></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```